# How to avoid assembly compilation before application start

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-assembly, roslyn

I want to use the Entity-Framework Database First in my application. My problem is, that the database schema we were using is not very static and can be customized in some cases (If the customer needs more tables to store some individual information). My idea was, to automatically generate an assembly, which contains the EF DbContext whith Roslyn, as explained in this [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146289/2630261). But i think this is not a very handy solution, because i have to compile the assembly and needs to load it form a directory, where the executing user has read and write access (like AppData, ...). Is there a better solution for my problem? Because i want to avoid compiling an assembly dynamically.

**Edit**
I think it needs to be an assembly, because the not customized product should use the same assembly for using the Entity-Framework. (I hope this makes sense).

Comment: How often does the database schema change? If not very often, it might be a solution that an administrator re-creates the assembly after each schema change and places it in the application folder. Users of the application can access the assembly there as they need to have Read permissions to run the application anyway.